# how can i make an image quality compare between 2 different formats?

Tags: image-quality, jpg, image-format, video

I'm writing about the new [Alliance for Open Media (AOM) AV1 codec](https://aomedia.googlesource.com/av1-spec/). I'm looking to compare it to the older JPG on the same image to show the quality difference.

While looking I couldn't find any images that I could use under CC3 or lower so I decided to make my own comparison.

My question is, how do I make it in a proper way to lower the quality of the images to the point where it will not show the correct difference between AV1 and JPG?

Comment: I don't really understand. You put the images side by side and then you decide which one looks better.

Answer (score 1):

One great way to see the difference between one image quality and the other while actively adjusting various parameters is available within Photoshop by using the 'Save for Web' option <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. This allows you to see the original image side by side in either a 2-up or 4-up view, while you change the image type, quality, or size in the same task.

[image: Photoshop Save For Web]

You can also just see the original image alone on screen, which has additional data below that will show file size and load time based on modem speed, hopefully this will show the data you need for the new codec compared to an older JPG

Comment: does photoshop support AV1?

Comment: You mentioned comparing it to a JPG, so I assumed you would would want to compare a still image to another still. If you want to show the file as AV1 it would not work in Photoshop as it does not play video files.

Comment: AV1 in general is a video format but is also used for normal images, it's a format that google and other plan to use to replace JPG and other old formats

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/supported-file-formats-photoshop-cs6.html This is a list of what photoshop supports, it doesn't seem like they have caught up with the new codec yet as it is not in the list, sorry!